# Несмотря на правильно указанные тэг и класс, парсинг не работает

Tags: python, парсер, requests, beautiful-soup

Хочу запарсить все названия компаний которые есть на бирже NYSE, но почему-то, несмотря на правильные тэг и класс, при парсинге данные не собираются.
Ссылка: https://www.economicdata.ru/stocks.php?menu=stocks-by-exchange&exchange=NYSE&tname=New+York+Stock+Exchange
Вот код:

```
url = 'https://www.economicdata.ru/stocks.php?menu=stocks-by-exchange&exchange=NYSE&tname=New+York+Stock+Exchange&page=1'
response = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS)
html_data = bs(response.text, features='html.parser')
corps = html_data.find_all('td', _class='  sorting_1')
corps = [corp.text for corp in corps]
print(corps)
```

[image: Вот тэг и класс]

Вывод программы : [ ]

Comment: Ну там явно же `JavaScript` генерит контент. Используйте `Selenium`

Comment: То есть по сути написать тот же код, но с селениумом?

Comment: Если хотите именно с таким поиском данных по классу, то да. Но подождите немного, сейчас я вам напишу ответ как это всё проще сделать можно

Answer (score 1):

В том виде, как вы хотите парсить эту страницу, вам нужно, чтобы работал `JavaScript`, классы расставляет похоже он. Для этого вам нужно использовать `Selenium`.

Но поскольку на сайте, как я вижу, присутствуют табличные данные, то можно использовать для парсинга модуль `Pandas`, он сам достанет все данные из таблички в удобном виде:

```
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.economicdata.ru/stocks.php?menu=stocks-by-exchange&exchange=NYSE&tname=New+York+Stock+Exchange&page='
data = []
for i in range(1,10000):
    print(i, end=',')
    df = pd.read_html(url+str(i))[0]
    if not df.shape[0]:
        break
    data.append(df)
print()
all_df = pd.concat(data, ignore_index=True)
print(all_df['Название компании'].values)
```

Вывод:

```
['Agilent Technologies, Inc.' 'Alcoa Corporation' 'AAC Holdings, Inc.' ...
 'Zoetis Inc.' 'Zuora, Inc.' 'Zymeworks Inc.']
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!